# How do you write the TSQL to calculate duration

Tags: t-sql

using the following table and data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AccountStatus](
[Id] [INT] NOT NULL,
[AccountId] [VARCHAR](15) NOT NULL,
[Status] [VARCHAR](15) NOT NULL,
[DateChanged] [DATETIME] NOT NULL
)

INSERT AccountStatus (Id,AccountId,Status,DateChanged) VALUES (1 , 'A', 'Imported', '1/1/2014')
INSERT AccountStatus (Id,AccountId,Status,DateChanged) VALUES (1 , 'A', 'Validated', '1/12/2014')
INSERT AccountStatus (Id,AccountId,Status,DateChanged) VALUES (1 , 'A', 'Contacted', '1/21/2014')
INSERT AccountStatus (Id,AccountId,Status,DateChanged) VALUES (1 , 'A', 'Qualified', '2/1/2014')
INSERT AccountStatus (Id,AccountId,Status,DateChanged) VALUES (1 , 'A', 'Closed', '2/10/2014')
```

How would one create output using tql showing the duration a given account was in a status?

The values are immutable and will never be updated.

I am looking for

```
Status | Start | End | Duration
```

I am have a real brain freeze.

Thanks

G

Comment: Duration based on what? Since status changed? Try to be more clear. Provide sample data and expected results if possible

Comment: Your problem is that your database is incorrectly designed for the information you want to pull from it. You should not have date changed, you should have startdate and end date.

Comment: yes, determining duration is a guessing game here.

Comment: Please provide data samples. if you insert a new reocrd everytime teh status changes it might be possible with a self join although never performanct or simple, but if you are updating records, what you want is not possible.

Comment: I have updated the question, thanks for pointing out what I needed to do to make things clearer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your problem correctly, I would use the following approach.
Please note that the code is not tested as you did not supply data (I wrote the code "in the air").
You would be making it a lot simpler to get answers if you post DDL & Data with your questions.

```
--  First sequence all Statuses, on a per account basis
;WITH StatusSeq AS
(
    SELECT   Id 
            ,Seq    = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountID ORDER BY DateChanged)
            ,AccountId
            ,[Status]
            ,DateChanged
    FROM dbo.AccountStatus
)
--  Second: Join the table to itself, so that on the right hand side
--          of the current row, you read the Status tha immediately followed
SELECT   T1.AccountID
        ,T1.[Status]
        ,StartDT    = T1.DateChanged
        ,EndDT      = T2.DateChanged
        --  I've chosen to show the date difference as days here, 
        --  you may want to choose something else
        ,Duration   = DATEDIFF(DAY, T1.DateChanged, T2.DateChanged)
FROM StatusSeq  T1
JOIN StatusSeq  T2  ON T1.Seq = T2.Seq - 1
```

Comment: I updated the post, thanks for letting me know how to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a row for Start and End:

```
SELECT Status,
  MIN(DateChanged) AS [Start],
  MAX(DateChanged) AS [End],
  MAX(DateChanged) - MIN(DateChanged) AS [Duration]
FROM AccountStatus
GROUP BY Status
```

You will have to play around with `Duration` using `CONVERT`